# How to attach an external library to Protractor config file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor, automated-tests

Here's the library:

```
//library.js
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.login = function(user_login, user_password) {   
    var input;      
    input = element(by.model('loginInfo.login'));
    input.sendKeys(user_login);
    expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe(user_login);     
    input = element(by.model('loginInfo.password'));
    input.sendKeys(user_password);
    expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe(user_password);        
    browser.sleep(1000);
    browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
    browser.sleep(1000);
};
```

And this is my config file:

```
   //config.js
   var lib = require("./library.js");
   exports.config = {
     directConnect: true,
   onPrepare: function() {
      browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
   },

   // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
   capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
   },

   // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
   framework: 'jasmine',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
   specs: ['messages.js'],


   // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
     defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000
   }
 };
```

And here's how I'm calling the login fn in the messages.js file:

```
  lib.login('xxx', 'yyyyy');
```

However, this last line above is giving me an error: 'lib is not defined'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to run a protractor test from your library.js file.

Instead of doing that, following the guidelines that http://www.protractortest.org/#/ instructs.  That is, the config.js file is for configuring the environment and the spec.js file is for testing.  As such, try this instead:

```
/*
 *  library-spec.js
 */

var input;      
describe('Login Test', function() {
    it('should enter login information and send the Enter key to login', function() {
        input = element(by.model('loginInfo.login'));
        input.sendKeys(user_login);
        expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe(user_login);     

        input = element(by.model('loginInfo.password'));
        input.sendKeys(user_password);
        expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe(user_password);        

        browser.sleep(1000);
        browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
        browser.sleep(1000);
    });

});
```

And the config file will look like:

```
//config.js
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    },

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
    framework: 'jasmine',

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
    // protractor is called.
    specs: ['library-spec.js'],


    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000
    }
};
```

However, if you need that library.js file to be run before each or before all your tests, put it into your `messages.js` file.

From your `messages.js` file, within your `describe` block you would add:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    lib(username, password); //where username and password are string vars
});
```

or

```
beforeAll(function() {
    lib(username, password); //where username and password are string vars
});
```

And, as a final note, if you leave your library.js file as is, here is some cleanup:

```
//library.js
module.exports = login;

function login(user_login, user_password) {   
    var input;      
    input = element(by.model('loginInfo.login'));
    input.sendKeys(user_login);
    expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe(user_login);     
    input = element(by.model('loginInfo.password'));
    input.sendKeys(user_password);
    expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe(user_password);        
    browser.sleep(1000);
    browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
    browser.sleep(1000);
};
```

Note how the module.exports line replaces the line that you had.  Also I've changed the exports.login to `function login`.  Then you would...

```
var login = require('./login');

login('user', 'pass');
```

where it will be needed.

Comment: Nope, library.js is not a test script, it's a library with common methods that I want to use for several scripts. What I want to find is a way to use those methods, but I don't know how/where to call them. Conf.js must call a test script, not a library.

Comment: Okay, follow the second half of this answer, then. Simply `var library = require('library')();`  Then you can call your methods from the library as `library.login()`.  See this blog post I wrote over the weekend that should help you out. http://www.assertselenium.com/angularjs/protractor-jasmine-pre-post-processing-methods/

Comment: I would also suggest not putting `expect` statements in your libraries that are expected to "do stuff".  Leave the expect statements to your actual spec tests.  That is, have a spec.js file that tests login specifically. But leave your login library expect free, but the assumption is login was previously tested, no need to repeat the test for simply logging in.